# Encrypt Parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I have a codeigniter program where I want to encrypt parameter data sent via ajax. The program code is as follows:

```
   $("#order").on("click", function () {
        var ord = $('#order').val();
          $.ajax({
             url:"<?php echo base_url('crud/order/'.encrypt_url("Here, I want to add it.")); ?>", 
             type: "get",
            //data: {ord: ord},
            success:function(result){
              console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

My question is, can I put the ord variable inside the encrypt_url function?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your JS code is in a view (meaning not a .js file), I don't see why you can't use your encrypt_url function. This can easily be tested by actually running you code and inspecting the source code afterward. I'm not sure if your function is custom or if you're trying to use Code Igniter's encrypt function. If it's the latter, I suggest you read the documentation as you're not using it correctly. https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encrypt.html